# ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0: Convert XY data to shapefile

Tags: csv, coordinates, latitude-longitude, arcgis, shapefile

I've displayed my XY data on my basemap, but when I right-click the layer and select "data" it says "export table" instead of "export data" so I can't choose the feature class shapefile. My data are in a CSV format, my headers are within the 1-10 limit, the data are formatted as text, and tried uploading this thing a whole bunch of different ways and it still thinks its a table. What am I missing?

The data looks like this:
*Group.1 (2005 -> 2020), Group.2 (1 -> 47)

```
   Group.1 Group.2 latitude   longitude
1    2005       1   25.66644 -80.26327
2    2006       1   25.68155 -80.25509
3    2007       1   25.62914 -80.28869
4    2008       1   25.62917 -80.28873
5    2009       1   25.62925 -80.28862
6    2010       1   25.62921 -80.28866
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong export option. All you have to do is right-click your displayed XY data > scroll to data > Export Features (not export table). Change the output location from your geodatabase to another folder of your choosing, change the Output name and ArcGIS Pro will autofill ".shp" at the end - click "OK" at the bottom right and POOF! Shapefile saved.

This video helped me get there:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vxfBK_afMw